# How can I measure values of Performance Counters of Desktop application in TestComplete through fixed gaps of time?

Tags: c#, performance-testing, testcomplete

I’m testing a Desktop application with the help of TestComplete. Application is written on C# for Windows. I can measure values of Performance Counters(CPU, Memory) in TestComplete after each action in my script that was performed in Application under test. 
How can I measure values of Performance Counters in TestComplete in another way - through fixed gaps of time (e.g., every10 seconds) – no matter if any actions were performed with an application? Is it possible? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can imagine is using the Timer object. You can use it to post an event record to the test log every 10 seconds and this will force TC to capture the performance data. When analyzing the test results, just filter out event messages and you will see a clean log.

```
function test()
{
  initPCTimer();
  // Test actions
}

function initPCTimer()
{
  var timer = Utils.Timers.Add(1000, "Unit1.pcTimer", true);
}

function pcTimer()
{
  Log.Event("Performance Counter Tick");
}
```